# Как обрезать с правой стороны до определенного символа?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть строки с полным адресом. `Улица, 5, кв 520`. Я пытаюсь обрезать так строку, чтобы осталось только `кв 520`. Но только получается с левой стороны. Пытался через `rtrim`, но безрезультатно, выводилась строка без изменений.

На вход: Улица, 5, кв 520
На выход: кв 520

```
substring(premises.short_address, 0, strpos(premises.short_address, ' кв') + 1)
```

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: `select SUBSTRING('Улица, 5, кв 520' FROM 'кв \d+$')`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо)